# What is the "get" keyword before a function in a class?

Tags: javascript, methods, getter

What does `get` mean in this ES6 class?  How do I reference this function?  How should I use it?

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

Comment: It’s most likely just a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) but inside a class instead of an object. It’s not really ES6-specific.

Comment: @Xufox how do you mean its not ES6 specific?

Comment: @KeithNicholas: That it worked in ES5 the same.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Getters exist since ES5, I think. The only thing that is ES6 here is the `class` syntax, but getters are nothing new.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It means the function is a getter for a property.

To use it, just use it's name as you would any other property:

```js
'use strict'
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

var p = new Polygon(10, 20);

alert(p.area);
```

Comment: Classes are implicitly in strict mode btw. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code

Comment: @KitSunde - at least on my browser (Chrome, Win7), without that statement I get console errors instead of working sample. And this is not part of "The Answer", much like the "Run code snippet" button isn't.

Comment: Can you not just call `p. calcArea`? if not, why not?

Comment: Are the get / set keywords just syntactical sugar - since a call to Polygon.calcArea() wil also act as a getter as well ?

Comment: so function get ```get``` keyword can't have parameter?

Comment: @CraigO.Curtis seems like it. Simply just a matter of declarative programming. Using the word 'get' implies that you are retrieving something, which is more intuitive than a function name by itself. Look at  ```get fullName``` and ```fullName()```. The former is more explicit in what is being done.

Answer (score 92):

### Summary:

The `get` keyword will bind an object property to a function. When this property is looked up now the getter function is called. The return value of the getter function then determines which property is returned.

### Example:

```js
const person = {
    firstName: 'Willem',
    lastName: 'Veen',
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

}

console.log(person.fullName);
// When the fullname property gets looked up
// the getter function gets executed and its
// returned value will be the value of fullname
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the practical example!

Comment: I think I can simplify it even further. The 'get' lets you treat a class method, as if it were a simple property in an object. If you leave off the 'get', you can still access the value by calling .area() instead of just .area

Answer (score 27):

It is getter, same as Objects and Classes in OO JavaScript. From the MDN Docs for [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.